# CodeFirst: Cannot open database "MyDatabase " requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'MyDomain\MyUser'

Tags: sql-server, ef-code-first

So I've been getting this error all of a sudden, and I have no idea how to resolve it. `MyDomain\MyUser` is listed under server users, but since I'm using CodeFIrst, the database is not created yet, so I can't add `MyDatabase` to the user.

Here is my code:

ConnectionString:

```
<add name="MyDatabaseConnection" connectionString="Data Source=myServer; Database=MyDatabase.sdf;Trusted_Connection=True;Persist Security Info=True;Pooling=false" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Code:

```
public class MyDbContext: DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext()
        : base("MyDatabaseConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserConfiguration());
    }
}


public class UserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("User");
        Property(u => u.ID).HasColumnName("UserID").HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    }
}


protected void Application_Start()
{
    Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(new MyDbContextInitializer());
    using (MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext())
    {
        db.Database.Initialize(false);
    }
    ...
}

public class MyDbContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(MyDbContextcontext)
    {
        base.Seed(context);
        SeedMembership();
    }

    private void SeedMembership()
    {
        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabaseConnection"].ConnectionString, "System.Data.SqlClient", "User", "UserID", "UserName", true);
        WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount("doe1", "password11", new { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue, try changing your connection string to:

```
<add name="MyDatabaseConnection" connectionString="Data Source=myServer; Database=MyDatabase.sdf;Trusted_Connection=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

So just remove `Persist Security` and `Pooling`. See if that works

Comment: I had MultipleActiveResultSets=True. Removing this fixed a similar problem.

Answer (score 3):

- Open the IIS Management Console
- Open the Application Pools node
- Select the Application Pool which corresponds to your website
- Right click the Application Pool and select "Advanced Settings"
- Select Identity in Process Model section
- Choose LocalSystem

[image]

Comment: What can I do if I am using IIS Express?